# Index disable/rebuild throws Columnstore index data compression error

Tags: sql-server, columnstore

I have added a columnstore index to the cube.partition_daily table

Error message:

Msg 10799, Level 16, State 1, Line 123
This is not a valid data compression setting for a columnstore index. Please choose COLUMNSTORE or COLUMNSTORE_ARCHIVE compression.

When running an index disable and rebuild between a call of 2 procs that essentially insert data into the cube.partition_daily table

```
ALTER INDEX ALL ON cube.partition_daily DISABLE;

EXEC cube.populate_daily

ALTER INDEX ALL
ON cube.partition_daily
REBUILD
WITH (FILLFACTOR = 100, DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE);
```

Why is this error message being thrown?

Answer (score 2):

From the [MS doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) :

*Specifying ALL causes the statement to fail if one or more indexes are in an offline or read-only filegroup or the specified operation is not allowed on one or more index types*

DATA_COMPRESSION cannot be PAGE for COLUMNSTORE index.